# Using accepts_nested_attributes_for, has_many and creating just one entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a Page with many Comments. Many users can access this page and submit comments. I view the comments on another Page that is private.

#### models/page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

#### models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### views/pages/show.html.erb relevant section

```
<%= form_for @page, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <% f.fields_for :comments do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.text_area :content, :rows => 1 %>
   <%= builder.submit "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
def show
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  @page.comments.build
  @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
end
```

The issue here is that I do not want to have the user see multiple fields for comments. Yet, if I do `<% f.fields_for :comment do |builder| %>` then it throws an error because it doesn't know what one comment is, and only wants to deal with multiple.

Essentially, the user should be able to submit a single comment on a page, which has many comments, and have that automatically associated with the page. As a secondary thing, I need to have the user's id (accessible through current_user.id via Devise) associated with the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<% f.fields_for :comments, f.object.comments.build do |fc| %>
  <!-- rest of form -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. I'd never have thought of that syntax before.

Comment: I agree with Alex Bartlow's comment.  Here are the relevant api docs:
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for
Search through that page for "It’s also possible to specify the instance to be used" and you'll see the code example for it.

Also, to add in the user_id into the comments form, use a hidden_field_tag: `fc.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id`.  Here are the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Answer (score 0):

could you use nested resources?     basically in the routes.rb...

```
resources :pages do 
  resources :comments 
end
```

then in the comments controller you can find the pages by page_id 
or something like that..   Don't recall exact syntax off top of head..